# Initialize Database connection in Jersey REST webapp

Tags: database, jersey, initialization

I want to make database queries in my Jersey REST webapp. The ideal situation would be to find a way where the database connection is initialised once at the first app run. Afterwards I only get the instance of DAOFactory object in my REST class and make the queries in the methods. I am using mysql connector. Is there a way to find a way to do it in Jersey? In JSF it was possible - I just used an application-scoped bean when I run the code. Moreover it would be good if I could access the `ServletContext` object inside this method cause I would like to use it's `getResourceAsStream()` method to read the database connection parameters from `WEB-INF/dao.properties` file. But the 'only once per app initialisation' is the crucial part here.